# How i can install thirdy party Camel Component?

Tags: maven, apache-camel, quarkus

I have a jar camel, I want to install in my maven and use in my route like uri.

I tried to add it to my local maven repository like this:

```
.\mvnw install:install-file "-Dfile=.\transformer-camel-component-2.0.3-03.jar" "-DgroupId=com.tracegroup.transformer.camelcomponent" "-DartifactId=map1" "-Dversion=2.0.3-03" "-Dpackaging=jar"
```

And then I add this dependency in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tracegroup.transformer.camelcomponent</groupId>
    <artifactId>map1</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3-03</version>
</dependency>
```

After I went to my routebuilder trying to use this route:

```
from("file://inputFile")
.to("txfrmr:${body}");
```

but the "txfrmr" is not present in the suggestion and when I compile the code it returns:

```
in route: Route(route1)[From[file://inputFile] -> [To[txfrmr:${body}]]... because of No endpoint could be found for: txfrmr://$%7Bbody%7D, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar
```

Comment: Creating a custom component is more complicated than that. For example, do you have in your archive the file `META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/txfrmr`? Did you read this article https://camel.apache.org/manual/writing-components.html?

Comment: This component is already a Camel Component, i want only to install. There is this META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/txfrmr yet

Comment: It is hard to help if we can't reproduce, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

With Quarkus, Camel components are discovered at build time. If your custom component does not have a Jandex index, then you need to request that Quarkus index your component dependency by adding some additional configuration to `application.properties`.

```
quarkus.index-dependency.map1.group-id=com.tracegroup.transformer.camelcomponent
quarkus.index-dependency.map1.artifact-id=map1
```

Afterwards, your custom `txfrmr` URI scheme should be resolvable.